# Parsing Push Notification Data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, push-notification

I am getting push notification and they are getting displayed on iPhone very nicely. But for some reason I want to parse the following result that I am receiving in **didReceivedRemoteNotification** method for push notification.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    print("FFTF", "didReceiveRemoteNotification", userInfo)
  }
```

Following is what I get when I print the userInfo

```
    [AnyHashable("FcmNotificationStatus"): 3, AnyHashable("ListItemIds"): ["42D890C4-0804-4434-B137-0EECDEFEC319"], AnyHashable("UserId"): 15, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1582109***6, AnyHashable("Title"): MY App, AnyHashable("body"): Welcome., AnyHashable("aps"): {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 589****85]
```

This is response I am getting and from it I want to get the following fields that have specific types

- content-available  (Int)
- FcmNotificationStatus  (Int)
- ListItemIds  (String Array)
- UserId   (Int)

And I tried many things but I am getting my application crash. Is there anything that I can do to parse it easily? Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a dictionary. Parsing should be fairly straight forward.

```
let status = userInfo["FcmNotificationStatus"] as? Int
let ids = userInfo["ListItemIds"] as? [Int]
let title = userInfo["Title"] as? String
let body = userInfo["body"] as? String
```

I cannot give a more detailed answer as to why you are getting these errors without you showing your code and explaining what errors your getting

[This guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) explains some of the concepts. An excert...

```
@available(iOS 10, *)

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}
```

You will not always receive notifications in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you should use the delegate methods mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: one more field is added and I tried this and it has given me error

Comment: please see question agaain

Comment: `aps` is `JSON`. So you just need to parse it as such

Comment: I tried your above given line, every thing is returned as nil

Comment: let me see the guide you have just put

Comment: show the code which prints the information in your question

Comment: its simple one line of code to print all user info. But any how I am updating question

Comment: I am just printing the userInfo. But I really want to go inside that

Comment: I dont see why you are getting nil on those values. I dont have FCM setup to check it.